# distribution of electric charges

Tags: electrostatics

In electricity courses, in the lesson on static fields, at some point all teachers say "let's consider a large rectangular metal plate where the density of charges is uniform", and then they proceed to show, using Gauss's law, that the electric field is uniform in the volume above the plate.

I don't see why a large metal plate, electrostatically charged, would "obviously" have roughly uniform electric charge density on its surface, away from the borders.

A classical argument explains that there can be no charge inside the volume of the plate, because it would create an electric field, and therefore a current until things settle. On the faces, the e-field is everywhere perpendicular to the surface, therefore no force is exerted on the charges there, and the configuration, whatever it is, is stable. But why would the charges necessarily be uniformly distributed on the sides (except for local border effects)?

Mathematically speaking, on one side, to compute the distribution of charges, one would have to find the one which minimizes the electrostatic potential energy (thanks to V. for the insight). I suppose there exist softwares to compute these distributions, but I don't know of any.

Comment: Now if you imagine an infinitely large plate, the electric field would have no way to go except absolutely sideways. You get what I mean?

Comment: A rectangular metal plate will usually not have a uniform charge density. Except when there is a second plate very close that carries an opposite charge or is grounded. Therefore a plastic plate would make a better example. At least than it's possible to achieve a roughly uniform charge density.

Comment: @busukxuan That's the classical argument. And it's fine... as long as you imagine an infinite plane. But I have never come across an infinite plane in real life. And I don't see why a large plane is evidently a rough model of an infinite one.

Comment: @SpiderPig A non conducting plate is an entirely different matter. There things are clear: we can place the charges wherever we like. My problem concerns a conducting plate. And putting two next to each other, to make a capacity, doesn't change the question.

Comment: The charge distribution is not uniform. But if you are only interested in the region close to the center, very very far away from the edge, then the edge effect can be ignored. And the density in this region is roughly uniform.

Comment: @Andy You mean, like how charge is distributed most on the surface of conducting solids?